# On the proof of the going-up and down theorem

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, proof-explanation, localization

I have some questions regarding the proof of the going-up and down theorem (Theorem 0.2.6) from [here](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/harder/Manuscripts/buch/Algnumbtheory.pdf) (p. 4).

First,

> Why are the prime ideals $\mathfrak q\in \operatorname{Spec}(B)$ for
>   which $\mathfrak q\cap A= \mathfrak p$ exactly the elements in
>   $\operatorname{Spec}(B\otimes_A(A/\mathfrak p)_{(0)})$?

<s>Second, I do understand why $B\otimes_A (A/\mathfrak p)_{(0)}$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $(A/\mathfrak p)_{(0)}$ (basically, by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037072/is-this-tensor-product-of-two-modules-finitely-generated) argument), but I don't understand why it is a (finitely generated) $(A/\mathfrak p)_{(0)}$-algebra.</s>

**Update 1:** Alright, I believe I managed to answer the second question. We have $B\otimes_A (A/\mathfrak p)_{(0)}=B_{(0)}\otimes_A (A/\mathfrak p)=B_{(0)}/\mathfrak pB_{(0)}$. Now $B_{(0)}/\mathfrak pB_{(0)}$ is a quotient ring, so multiplication is defined there. It is also an $(A/\mathfrak p)_{(0)}$-module (vector space) and hence an $(A/\mathfrak p)_{(0)}$-algebra. It is finitely generated as an algebra because it is finitely generated as a module (vector space).

**Update 2:** A misprint in the claim fixed (it is also present in the proof).

Comment: You may want to review the followings: 1) There exists a 1-1 correspondence between the set of ideals of $R$ containing $I$ and the set of ideals of $R/I$. 2) For any multiplicatively closed set $S$ of $R$, the set of prime ideals of $S^{-1}R$ consists of the prime ideals which does not meet $S$. Lastly, you just need to observe that $B \otimes (A/p)_{(0)} \cong B \otimes A/p \otimes A_p \cong B/pB \otimes S^{-1}A \cong S^{-1}B/pB$ where $S = A-p$.